# Show secret key of django-otp TOTPDevice

Tags: python, django

I am using `django-otp` for 2FA on my Django app.

In the [docs](https://django-otp-official.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html?highlight=TOTPDevice#django_otp.plugins.otp_totp.models.TOTPDevice) we are given `TOTPDevice.config_url`, which can be used to generate a QR code or as a link to set up 2FA with Google Auth or similar.

How can I get ONLY the secret key from a `TOTPDevice` object? A workaround would be to get the parameter from the URL, but it sounds odd there is no built-in way to get it?

I noticed a `TOTPDevice.key` which is in hex format, but converting into ascii or utf-8 does not give the correct secret key.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working with `django-otp` too, so I came across your question.
Don't know if you still need an answer but maybe it's helpful for other devs out there.

I think the best way to get the secret from the key URI looks like this:

```
from base64 import b32encode

device = TOTPDevice.objects.get(pk=1)
secret_key = b32encode(device.bin_key).decode('utf-8')
```

At least, this is what `TOTPDevice.config_url` does.

Hope this helps

Comment: Right, I was hoping there was a way to directly get it as utf-8, but I guess not. Your solution is an other valid workaround.

Personally I simply extracted it from `config_url`.